# Equivalent using for-loop instead do-while-loop

Tags: c, for-loop, do-while

I was wondering instead of using a do-while loop, what is the equivalent for-loop or any other combination of loops in c?

Comment: What do you think?  The main issue with a do-while (vs straight `while`) is that the loop always iterates at least once.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Any sort of a loop can be constructed from a combination of an infinite "forever" loop, and a conditional `break` statement.

For example, to convert

```
do {
    <action>
} while (<condition>);
```

to a `for` loop, you can do this:

```
for (;;) {
    <action>
    if (!<condition>) break;
}
```

You can use the same trick to convert a `do`/`while` loop to a `while` loop, like this:

```
while (true) {
    <action>
    if (!<condition>) break;
}
```

Moreover, the loop is not needed at all: any of the above can be modeled with a label at the top and a `goto` at the bottom; that is  a common way of doing loops in assembly languages. The only reason the three looping constructs were introduced into the language in the first place was to make the language more expressive: the `do`/`while` loop conducts author's idea much better than any of the alternatives shown above.

Comment: So the  if (!<condition>) break; would be the same as the do part?

Comment: @deathshot Yes, a "breaking" condition is the negated "continuation" condition.

Answer (score 2):

There is no other loop that executes the loop content at least once, as do-while does. Of course you could emulate do-while with a flag and a while loop:

```
do {
    A;
} while (B)
```

becomes

```
int flag=1;
while (flag || B) {
    flag=0;
    A;
}
```

but that's not really an alternative, it just obscures your original intent.

Answer (score 2):

The following three loops are all equivalent:

```
#define FALSE (0)
#define TRUE  (!(FALSE))

do
{
    status = getStatus();
}
while(status == TRUE);

status = TRUE;
while(status == TRUE)
{
    status = getStatus();
}

for(status = TRUE; status == TRUE; status = getStatus())
{
}
```

Comment: Oh, I was really hinting that that would idiomatically be written as `status`, not `status == true`.

Comment: Just trying to be explicit for the sake of new programmers. It definately looks better use `while(status)`.

Comment: And shouldn't that be `status = TRUE;` as well (rather than `true`) for the assignment before the while?