# How to convert do while loop to while loop in C++?

Tags: c++, loops, while-loop, do-while, control-structure

I have written a C++ program to let the users entering positive numbers using a `do while` loop. Notwithstanding, when I try to convert the `do while` loop into a `while` loop, the expected output is not the same as do while loop. The code is as below:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n;

    do
    {
        cout << "Enter a non-negative integer: ";
        cin >> n;
        if (n < 0)
        {
            cout << "The integer you entered is negative. " << endl;
        }

    }
    while (n < 0);

    return 0;
}
```

The terminal requires the user to reenter the number until it is positive for the above code that I have written. However, I try to convert the `do while` loop to `while` loop as shown below, there is no output at all.

May I know which part I have written wrongly? Thank you.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n;

    while (n < 0)
    {
        cout << "Enter a non-negative integer: ";
        cin >> n;
        if (n < 0){
            cout << "The integer you entered is negative. " << endl;
         }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Just assign any negative value to n before the loop

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Equivalent using for-loop instead do-while-loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20735358/equivalent-using-for-loop-instead-do-while-loop)

Comment: @Ch3steR the problem is the output is not the same since I followed the tutorial from google and youtube.

Comment: In the second code example, since `n` is uninitialized, it may coincidentally contain a negative number, or it may not. The behavior, in particular whether the `while` loop condition will be `true` when first executed, is undefined.

Answer (score 1):

In the `while` version of your code, you do not know what the value of `n` is, as it is not initialized before you use it in the `while (n<0)` loop.

```cpp
int main()
{
    int n;
    // HERE YOU DO NOT KNOW IF n is NEGATIVE OR POSITIVE, YOU EITHER NEED TO INITIALIZE IT OR
    // ENTER IT by cin >> n
    while (n < 0)
    {
        cout << "Enter a non-negative integer: ";
        cin >> n;
        if (n < 0){
            cout << "The integer you entered is negative. " << endl;
         }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

You then need to rearrange a little bit to get the same ouput as well as to use the first input  of `n` which is out of the loop.

For instance, this will provide the same output:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n=-1;
    cout << "Enter a non-negative integer: ";
    cin >> n;
    while (n < 0)
    {

        if (n < 0)
        {
            cout << "The integer you entered is negative. " << endl;
            cout << "Enter a non-negative integer: ";
            cin >> n;
        }
        else
        {
            // if positive you get out of the loop
            break;
        }
 
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome. I added an attempt to make the same loop with a `while`. Of course, it is not the only solution but it is easy to understand

Answer (score 0):

You have to take the n before while(n<0) statement:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n;
    cout << "Enter a non-negative integer: ";
    cin >> n;
    while (n < 0)
    {
        cout << "Enter a non-negative integer: ";
        cin >> n;
    if (n < 0)
            cout << "The integer you entered is "
                 << "negative. " << endl;
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Or you may initialize it with negative number:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n=-1;
    
    while (n < 0)
    {
        cout << "Enter a non-negative integer: ";
        cin >> n;
    if (n < 0)
            cout << "The integer you entered is "
                 << "negative. " << endl;
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I see. So I'd need to repeat the cout and cin statement twice to get the same output as the do while loop. Thank you.